# Retrieve "self" function in the strict-mode JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, strict-mode

I often need in a function `f` to retrieve a name of the method that points to `f`. For example. Let's say we have a `getMethodName(obj, methodFunction)` function that uses `foreach` on `obj` to find a property that is a link to `methodFunction`:

```
obj = { 
    foo : function() {
        var myName = getMethodName(obj, arguments.callee); // "foo"
    }
}
```

How do I do this in **strict mode** where `arguments.callee` is deprecated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it. And you shouldn't do it in the first place, this is magic, your function should not depend on its caller etc. Change your design in order to make it work again.

`arguments.callee` and `.caller` have not only been removed because of being bad style, but also because they defeat optimization. Namely inlining, you can't inline something if you depend on the caller, nor on the function, since the code might have just put somewhere without the function around it.

Read: http://whereswalden.com/2010/09/08/new-es5-strict-mode-support-now-with-poison-pills/

Comment: Why does the article start with "tl;dr"? I know what that means in general, but not in this context.

Comment: @Sime Well I guess the author's just making a joke here about the fact that his article is basically one giant wall of text

Comment: Aha, a joke then. That's probably it.

Comment: Yes, it was a joke -- or more precisely, a gentle dig at people unwilling to read articles more than a page or so in length.  :-)  (Also: yay for referrer logs!)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out, since I can't tell if you considered it, that if you simply supply a name to the function in the object literal, you can refer to it that way:

```
obj = { 
    foo : function METHODNAME() {
        var myName = getMethodName(obj, METHODNAME); // "foo"
    }
}
```

But beware: I think IE has a bug in release versions where this will define a function named `METHODNAME` in the enclosing scope (rather than making it accessible to that function only).  By spec, however, this is perfectly kosher and works perfectly fine so long as you use a name not found anywhere in the function itself, or in code passed to `eval` if the function can call `eval`.

Comment: But suppose I want to do

    addEventListener("event", myfun.bind(this));

I now can't remove this listener without storing it somewhere, right?  Because myfun.bind() returns a new function.

That's super-lame.

Comment: That sounds right.  Although I think "super-lame" is very much in the eye of the beholder -- it's just how the language and API work.  And how else could it?  Taking as a given that we don't want to expose GC behavior (so weak-reference-like behavior's out), you need some way to remove a listener you've previously added, that disambiguates among multiple listeners.  Isn't removal by specifying the reference to remove the natural way?  It's perhaps a bit awkward, but I'm not seeing a better way offhand.

Comment: Well, it worked great when I could use arguments.callee.  The argument being made is that you lose nothing without it -- just name the function.  I'm saying that in fact you do lose something, because you can't always name the function.  So now I have to choose between disabling strict mode and incurring the annoyance (and potential leaks) of keeping track of all these event listeners manually.

Comment: You can't name the function if it's a bound function in any case.  arguments.callee inside myfun is myfun, not the bound function that results from myfun.bind(this).  So the elimination of arguments.callee in strict mode functions shouldn't mean anything for your bound-function case.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: "arguments.callee inside myfun is myfun, not the bound function that results from myfun.bind(this)" -- I had no idea!  How sad.

Comment: Yes...but also perhaps no.  Consider that the hand-rolled bind implementations from which these semantics derived all also had arguments.callee as the original function, not the bound function.  The cowpaths were paved exactly as originally traveled.  And doing it this way means polyfills can be more correct and faithful to spec semantics.  Still, it's perhaps a tradeoff.